# How to get 3D bar graph in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, bar-chart

I use `bar3` in Matlab to plot a 3D bar plot. This is useful to quickly get a sense of values in a matrix or a 1-channel image read in as a matrix. When I switched to Octave, I could not find the bar3 function.

Is there any alternative to bar3 in Octave? Or a reimplementation by someone I could import and render the plot?

Comment: See http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/hist3-td4641286.html

Answer (score 0):

Not a 3D bar plot, but imagesc is quite useful as an alternative to bar3 for getting a visual sense of the values in a large matrix.